# Meteor reset password does not send email to user for password reset

Tags: meteor, nitrousio, password-recovery, reset-password, telescope

Meteor reset password does not send email to user for password reset.

There are not any errors.

In telescope app after clicking on "Email Reset Link" button it shows "Email sent", however the user does not receive an email for password reset.

**The problem had been solved partially. Because, after MAIL_URL installation (+Mailgun) it is still does not work. The problem can be related to nitrous.io, because nitrous.io box doesn't support SMTP.**

**Does someone had installed meteor app on nitrous.io and have mail notifications?
Does some of the nitrous.io developers can suggest something?**

Comment: Is the app running on a development server?  If so, it logs the e-mail to the console rather than sending it.  If not, check your [MAIL_URL environment variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email)

Comment: @richsilv Thank you for your answer. I am using nitrous.io, so it means that it logs the e-mail to the console rather than sending it, right? How can I change this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up an SMTP service (Meteor's own hosting uses [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/), but others are available), and set the environment variable `MAIL_URL` to match the details of your service, as documented [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email).

Ideally do this in the Nitrious.io environment before Meteor starts, but you can do it on startup if required as I assume it won't be required immediately:

```
process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@smtp.mailgun.org:587'; // (or equivalent for another provider)
```

Comment: Note that for Telescope specifically, you should also be able to configure `MAIL_URL` in your app's Settings panel.

Comment: @richsilv still does not work. I think there is some problem with nitrous.io, because nitrous.io box doesn't support SMTP.